# Negating POS-tagged sentence only AFTER negating word

Tags: php, regex

Consider the following string:

```
I am mad and will not ever set foot in that store again
```

I am using a POS-tagger to tag the string like this:

```
I/NN am/VBP mad/JJ and/CC will/MD not/RB ever/RB set/VBN foot/NN in/IN that/IN 
store/NN again/RB
```

Now, I'm using a regex to concatenate "not" to, a.o., verbs while ignoring the negating words (never, neither, etc.)

```
preg_replace(
  "/(\s)(?:(?!never|neither|dont|wont|not|no)(\w*))\/(JJ|MD|RB|VB|VBG|VBN)\b/", 
  "$1not$2",
  $sentence
);
```

This results in:

```
I am notmad and notwill notever notset foot in that store notagain
```

However, what I want is to only concatenate "not" to verbs that appear **AFTER** the (first) negating word. Notice `mad` and `will` instead of `notmad` and `notwill`:

```
I am mad and will notever notset foot in that store notagain
```

So I think first I should look for any negating word (never|neither|dont|wont|not|no) in the sentence, and only execute the regex from there. But how would I go about this?

Comment: So, for every word tagged with any of the tags (JJ|MD|RB|VB|VBG|VBN) *after* an instance of `not/RB`, `not` needs to be prepended to the word tagged as (JJ|MD|RB|VB|VBG|VBN)?

Comment: **after** an instance of never, neither, dont, wont, not or no. The original sentence, not the POS-tagged one, should be the reference, since neither for instance also be tagged as neither/DT, which is obviously a different tag from RB.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would seem to be using `preg_split` on your tagged sentence to split it into two parts: the part before the first negation word and the part after that negation word. Keep the delimiter (PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE) and then run the regex you wrote on the second part, after which you can simply concatenate these two strings together again. Finally, you can remove the PoS tags using a regex to get `I am mad and will notever notset foot in that store notagain`, i.e. without the PoS tags.